# Should I convert image into HttpPostedFileBase?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, image, httppostedfilebase

I need to post a form. One of the properties of my model is an image.

To do so I am using in fact 2 properties:

- Logo is a `Byte[]` and is used to show the image in display mode.
- LogoForPost is a `HttpPostedFileBase` and is used to upload image in edit mode.

I can **create easily**. I can **display easily**. My **problem is to modify**.

When I enter modify mode, and immediately press the submit button, I get an understandable (and predictable) message telling me that the LogoForPost property is required.

I could solve this problem easily by converting Logo into LogoForPost, but I guess it must be complicated to convert an image into an `HttpPostedFileBase`. 
In fact, there are multiple articles on StackOverFlow explaining how to convert an `HttpPostedFileBase` into a `Byte[]`, but not the other way round. This makes me think that perhaps I don't need to, and that there might be a better way to solve the problem.

Comment: Don't you make your life complicated? you have a stored image and you have a possibility to replace the imge by a new one. It is enough in case if you are not going to implement an image editor on your site.

Comment: Yaugen Vlasau: Can you please detail a little bit more? In fact I don't need any image editor. I just wan't to get rid of the required field validation.

Comment: please remove "required" attribute on your <input file> tag.  or a similar attibute that my be defined in your page script or in the script you load with your page

Comment: Ok, that might be a good move, but that 'removal' must depend on whether I am on edit mode or create mode. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised (with the help of Yaugen Vlasau) that it would be a lot easier to simply remove the required attribute depending on whether I am on edit mode (remove) or create mode (mantain required attribute).